How should I explain why it took my so long to get this stage?
I took an extra year to finish my degree due to severe mental health challenges, which also caused me to leave a prestigious graduate scheme. Antidepressants made me ill when I withdrew from them, and stress often makes me ill. I'm now pursuing a master's as my next step. How can I best explain this situation to future employers in a way that is honest but also highlights my resilience and commitment?

Do you want to explain the situation to employers?  Or are you afraid they'll ask the question?  Taking 5 years to complete a 4-year undergraduate program is pretty unremarkable.  I doubt it would ever come up.  Particularly if the undergraduate degree isn't even your terminal degree.

This doesn't need explaining. The degree is all that counts.

You are overthinking the number of years - it isn't a concern by any company. Please relax on that point. Getting comfortable and stable with your mental heath might take some practice. Being honest - if and when an issue comes up is important. You don't need to bring it up first.

Dont use your real name here

Taking an extra year is far from uncommon. People reconsider their majors, or take a break to earn more money, or to travel, or to see if they could make it in the arts, or whatever.  I can't vouch for your interviewer, but as long as you had some vaguely reasonable explanation of what you did during the break this really shouldn't cause any raised eyebrows. "I needed to take time off for medical treatment" is a reasonable explanation, and you aren't obligated to say what kind of treatment you needed.
BUT: If stress still "often makes you ill,"  going off the antidepressants may not have been the right choice. Talk to your doctor. Chronic depression is a legitimate, and treatable, medical condition, and if the drugs are doing their job, being on a maintenance dose for the rest of your life is successful treatment, not a personal failing.

I took a year off before my freshman college year; my official explanation was a combination of being tired of always being the youngest person in the class and wanting to spend a year doing volunteer work (which I did). But nobody ever asked.
